# fullcalendar 5 - Custom dayMaxEvents with function

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Is there a simple way for each user from a select box for example to define the DaymaxEvents option of fullcalendar ?

Maybe with batchRendering ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

ok i found it...sorry

calendar.setOption('dayMaxEvents', 5);